# Direction rtl and dot which goes to left

Tags: css, direction, text-align

I am using direction: rtl and text-align: justify on paragraph and there occurs a problem with dot at the end of paragraph.

example:

```
Hello, I am Peter.
```

is displayed as

```
.Hello, I am Peter
```

Could somebody explain me why the dot behaves like that and how to fix it ?

Thanks